# Pythonic way to convert a numpy array into another array with column indices

Tags: python, numpy

So, what I want to do, given this input:

```
a=np.array([[5, 1, 10], [2, 3, 4]])
```

convert into another np array:

```
[[(5, 0), (1, 1), (10, 2)], [(2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2)]]
```

What's the pythonic way to do this?

EDIT: I was using 1 indexing but 0 indexing also works. Added more context to clarify. Fixed a typo in initialization.

The column indices represent items. The values in each cell represent score for that item. What I want to do is to sort each row in decreasing order based on the score and grab the indices for further processing.

So, if I have the output as explained above, after sorting it'd look like:

```
[[(10, 2), (5, 0), (1, 1)], [(4,2), (3, 1), (2, 0)]]
```

and then I can grab the indices:

```
[[2, 0, 1],[2, 1, 0]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Logic for the conversion?

Comment: First, what did you try? (Perhaps in a non-pythonic way?) Second, what is the algorithm that you are trying to implement?

Comment: so, the column indices represent items and the values represent scores. What I want to do is sort each row using the scores and grab the column indices for further processing.

Comment: so, the output for the algorithm would be [[3, 1, 2],[1, 2, 3]]

Comment: i'm open to suggestions for simplifying

Comment: You sure about that output - `[[3, 1, 2],[2, 3, 4]]`?

Comment: oops, my bad ... second row was malformed ... i was also working with 1-indexing, but 0-indexing also works

Comment: Don't rush it. Take your time to explain the expected output for the sample. Add those into the question.

Comment: That `[[(10, 2), (5, 0), (1, 1)], [(2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2)]]` doesn't look like sorted in descending order for the second row.

Comment: fixed...should've not rushed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your `a` expression is missing []

```
In [231]: a=np.array([[5, 1, 10], [2, 3, 4]])  # add extra []
In [232]: a
Out[232]: 
array([[ 5,  1, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])
```

A list comprehension is the easiest way to produce the shown list

```
In [233]: [[(n,i+1) for i,n in enumerate(row)] for row in a]
Out[233]: [[(5, 1), (1, 2), (10, 3)], [(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3)]]
```

I could do it by concatenating `np.arange(1,4)` as well, but the inner elements wouldn't be tuples.  I'd have to use a structured array to get that kind of display.

This is the kind of 3d array we'd get with a concatenate:

```
In [234]: np.array(_)
Out[234]: 
array([[[ 5,  1],
        [ 1,  2],
        [10,  3]],

       [[ 2,  1],
        [ 3,  2],
        [ 4,  3]]])
```

A structured array with the same `tolist()` output:

```
In [244]: alist=[[(n,i+1) for i,n in enumerate(row)] for row in a]
In [245]: a3=np.array(alist, dtype='i,i')
In [246]: a3
Out[246]: 
array([[( 5, 1), ( 1, 2), (10, 3)],
       [( 2, 1), ( 3, 2), ( 4, 3)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Building direct:

```
In [254]: a2=np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[1],2),a.dtype)
In [255]: a2[:,:,0]=a
In [256]: a2[:,:,1]=np.arange(1,4)
In [257]: a2
Out[257]: 
array([[[ 5,  1],
        [ 1,  2],
        [10,  3]],

       [[ 2,  1],
        [ 3,  2],
        [ 4,  3]]])
```

or for the structured case:

```
In [258]: a2=np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[1]),dtype='i,i')
In [259]: a2['f0']=a
In [260]: a2['f1']=np.arange(1,4)
```

---

Same construction, but with the sorted values as described in the edits:

```
In [281]: idx=np.argsort(-a,axis=1)
In [282]: a1 = -np.sort(-a,1)
In [283]: a2=np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[1]),dtype='i,i')
In [285]: a2['f0']=a1
In [286]: a2['f1']=idx
In [287]: a2
Out[287]: 
array([[(10, 2), ( 5, 0), ( 1, 1)],
       [( 4, 2), ( 3, 1), ( 2, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Answer (score 2):

To get to the final output of corresponding column indices that represent the scores from corresponding rows in descending order, simply use [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) along each row by listing `axis` parameter as `1` or `-1` in case you are dealing with multi-dimensional arrays and then flip the columns with `[:,::-1]` or `[...,::-1]` for multi-dimensional arrays. Alternative way again with `argsort` would be to use negated version of input array. This way we won't be dealing with forming the stacked tuples of indices and their scores.

Thus, the two solutions with `np.argsort` would be -

```
np.argsort(a,axis=1)[:,::-1]
np.argsort(-a,axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [51]: a
Out[51]: 
array([[ 5,  1, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])

In [52]: np.argsort(a,axis=1)[:,::-1]
Out[52]: 
array([[2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]])

In [53]: np.argsort(-a,axis=1)
Out[53]: 
array([[2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: that solves all that i was trying to do. Thanks for the simple solution. However, since the original question was about converting to column indices, i'll mark the other answer as correct to avoid confusion.